# 'awareness on' vs. 'awareness of'

Tags: phrase-usage

There seem to be a not-insignificant sample of usage of "awareness on" in publications ranging from [reference](https://sentence.yourdictionary.com/awareness) to [academia](https://scholar.google.com.au/scholar?as_vis=0&q=%22awareness+on%22&hl=en&as_sdt=1,5&as_ylo=2019).

What separates it from "awareness of"? My first thought was that using "of" would be a binary "I am either aware or unaware of something", whereas "on" might point to nuanced knowledge of a field", but usage does not seem to bear that out.

Is this usage valid, and if so, what separates it from the more common case?

Comment: ***On*** is actually used. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22awareness%20on%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en and its usage appears to be increasing https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=awareness+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cawareness%20on%3B%2Cc0 though ***of*** remanins the  more used preposition - https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=awareness+on%2C+awareness+of+&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cawareness%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cawareness%20of%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Would you consider both usages to be synonymous, though, or might there be a difference?

Comment: I feel the difference  is like between *think on* vs *think of*.